# Stacking multiple columns into one using an if statement - vba (excel)

Tags: excel, vba

I need to to stack multiple columns into one using an if statement as the example below

Original table looks like the following:

| Type | ID | Name | State | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pay | 01 | Joe | NY | -5 | 0 |
| Pay | 02 | Ann | FL | -2 | -4 |
| Receive | 03 | Lee | TX | 1 | 0 |
| Pay | 04 | Ken | CA | 0 | -1 |
| Receive | 05 | John | NY | 3 | 2 |

I would like to have the columns Type, ID, X and Y to be copied from sheet1 to sheet2 using the following conditions:

- if Type = "Pay" and X <> 0 then copy columns "Type", "ID" and X * (-1)
- if Type = "Pay" and Y <> 0 then copy columns "Type", "ID" and Y * (-1)
- if Type = "Receive" and X <> 0 then copy columns "Type", "ID" and X
- if Type = "Receive" and Y <> 0 then copy columns "Type", "ID" and Y

I would Like the final result to look like the following:

| Type | ID | # |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pay | 01 | 5 | X |
| Pay | 02 | 2 | X |
| Receive | 03 | 1 | X |
| Receive | 05 | 3 | X |
| Pay | 02 | 4 | Y |
| Pay | 04 | 1 | Y |
| Receive | 05 | 2 | Y |

Please help me

Thanks Phil

Comment: See 2nd answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541905/convert-matrix-to-3-column-table-reverse-pivot-unpivot-flatten-normal)  Formula is not the best way to do this.  It is possible with variations of INDEX, but PowerQuery can do this dynamically and faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ScottCraner implied, you can obtain your desired output using `Power Query`, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365 Excel

- Select some cell in your original table
- `Data => Get&Transform => From Table/Range`
- When the PQ UI opens, navigate to `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table Name in Line 2 of the code.
- Replace the existing code with the **M-Code** below
- Change the table name in line 2 of the pasted code to your "real" table name
- Examine any comments, and also the `Applied Steps` window, to better understand the algorithm and steps

Note that your "conditions", when applied to the unPivot table, are the same as

- Filter out the zero values
- Multiple the "Pay" values by `-1`

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table33"]}[Content],

//delete unneeded columns
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(Source,{"Name", "State"}),

//set data type
    typeIt = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns",{
        {"Type", Text.Type},
        {"ID",   Text.Type},
        {"X",    Int64.Type},
        {"Y",    Int64.Type}
    }),

//unPivot, then remove the rows with zeros's
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(typeIt, {"Type", "ID"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", each ([Value] <> 0)),

//add column where Pay amount are multiplied by -1
//remove unneeded Value column
//Sort and reorder the columns
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "#", each if [Type]="Pay" then [Value] * -1 else [Value]),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Value"}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Removed Columns1",{{"Attribute", Order.Ascending}, {"ID", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"Type", "ID", "#", "Attribute"})
in
    #"Reordered Columns"
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent answer! It worked perfectly for my needs.